# Oracle Sql concatenating a string with a number value trims leading zero for numbers less than 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to concatenate two values and have something like

```
SELECT col1||col2 FROM tab1;
```

where col1 holds a string and col2 a number which works well as long as the value of col2 is greater than one. For values less than one the leading zero is trimed.
For example:

```
Select 'A ' || 1.1 from dual;
```

returns `A 1,1` but

```
Select 'A ' || 0.1 from dual;
```

returns `A ,1`.
How do i keep the leading zero and get for above example `A  0,10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you want one digit before and after the decimal place, use `to_char()`:

```
select 'A ' || to_char(0.1, 'FM0.0')
from dual;
```

You can handle more digits *before* the decimal place using:

```
select 'A ' || trim(to_char(0.1, '9999999990.0'))
from dual;
```

Comment: This solved my question. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: You probably want to use `'FM0.0'` for the first format mask, to avoid getting an extra space before the leading zero on positive numbers.